# Are "fast growing trees" a gimmick, or is this possible?

Tags: trees

I'm looking to get some shade and coverage, and just "nice to look at" natural scenery in my yard.  I stumbled upon the site [fast-growing-trees](http://www.fast-growing-trees.com/).

This almost seems ***Too Good To Be True***.  What are your thoughts on this?  Is this real?  Advised?  What's the downside?

Comment: This site is the usual.  Lots of pictures, not a lot of real information.  It's easy to make promises about trees as you can't really take them back ten years later when they are observed to be unsuitable.  Buy from a local grower, better to pay a little more and get a known quantity rather than cheap and surprising....unless you have a 100 acres..

Answer (score 3):

Having had a quick look at your link, they are not all fast growing trees - those that are have a growth rate per year listed. They appear also to be selling some 'mature' large plants - the drawback with those is, the older they are, the less easily they transplant into the ground compared with younger specimens.

And yes, there is a major drawback with fast growing plants, which is they may quickly outgrow the spot you've planted them in. Always check the ultimate height and spread of any tree or plant described as 'fast growing', and make your decision based on that rather than the overall speed of growth. Finding that information on the site you've linked to might be impossible though; in terms of using botanical names and height and spread, I couldn't find anything useful at all.

Answer (score 1):

There are [some trees](https://www.arborday.org/trees/TREEGUIDE/TreeDetail.cfm?ItemID=908) which, in suitable conditions and with suitable nutrition/water, can grow very fast. Those same trees also tend to be weak in the longer term (they break), and the growth rate may not be all that fast in your particular site, if your site is lacking soil, water or light.

They can serve a useful purpose in a landscape plan by giving what they give (quick tall tree) and then being ruthlessly removed as other, slower-growing trees grow to plan. Or they can serve as a renewable fiber resource in a plantation setting.